# Select department id, seniority based on hire_time and the ealierst date of hire date

Tags: sql, oracle

i have this task:
Select department id, the longest time of working based on months and time of the person who was hired as the first one

I wrote sthg like this:

```
SELECT department_id, min(hire_date) as earliest_hire_date, sysdate-hire_date dni
FROM employees
```

it generates the following error:

```
*ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"*
```

i use oracle. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a record that meets a certain criteria (which generally means you are going to need a WHERE clause). The criteria for the WHERE clause is the record with the min(hire_date). So:

```
 SELECT department_id, hire_date, sysdate-hire_date
 FROM employees
 WHERE hire_date = (SELECT min(hire_date) FROM employees);
```

Or something along those lines. IF this returns more than one record, you could probably just toss a GROUP BY or DISTINCT in there. If that doesn't squash the multiples then you'll have to implement further logic to pick the winner (in the even that multiple departments share the same "earliest hiring date").

You could also do something similar to what you were doing (Aggregating at min(hire_date)) and then order by that field picking out the top most record.

---

As for the error you were facing in your attempt, when you use an Aggregate function like `sum()`, `avg()`, `min()` and similar, then fields that are not being aggregated must be in the GROUP BY clause, which was absent in your query.

Answer (score 0):

You would fix your problem by using `min()` in the `select`:

```
select department_id, min(hire_date) as earliest_hire_date,
       sysdate - min(hire_date) as dni
from employees
group by department_id;
```

I'm not sure if this does what you really need -- your question doesn't have sample data, desired results, or a clear explanation of what you want.  On the other hand, it does fix the syntax error.